# Unresolved dependency error for ivy.xml

Tags: eclipse, liferay, portlet, ivy

I just created a liferay plugin project(Ant plugin) in eclipse IDE and I got this error  :

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type unresolved dependency:
>   com.liferay#com.liferay.ant.arquillian;1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: several
>   problems occurred while resolving dependency:
>   com.liferay#com.liferay.ant.arquillian;1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
>   {test=[default]}:     liferay-private: unable to get resource for
>   com/liferay#com.liferay.ant.arquillian;1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:
>   res=${ivy.repository.liferay.private.url}/com/liferay/com.liferay.ant.arquillian/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/com.liferay.ant.arquillian-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar:
>   java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol:
>   ${ivy.repository.liferay.private.url}/com/liferay/com.liferay.ant.arquillian/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/com.liferay.ant.arquillian-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar
>     liferay-private: unable to get resource for
>   com/liferay#com.liferay.ant.arquillian;1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:
>   res=${ivy.repository.liferay.private.url}/com/liferay/com.liferay.ant.arquillian/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/com.liferay.ant.arquillian-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom:
>   java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol:
>   ${ivy.repository.liferay.private.url}/com/liferay/com.liferay.ant.arquillian/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/com.liferay.ant.arquillian-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom ivy.xml /MyFirstPortlet-portlet Unknown IvyDE
>   Problem

It seems my ivy file cant resolve dependencies. My ivy.xml file is here
[image]

I checked http://ant.apache.org/ivy/maven link in ivy.xml and found out that it doesn't exist. I think that's the problem. If it is how can I correct my ivy.xml file?

Comment: Please paste a copy of the ivy file, rather than an incomplete image (crucial missing data off-screen to the right). In it's current form this question is unanswerable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change ivy.xml  as following;

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<ivy-module
 version="2.0"
 xmlns:m2="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/maven"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd"
>
 <info module="test-portlet" organisation="com.liferay">
  <extends extendType="configurations,description,info" location="../../ivy.xml" module="com.liferay.sdk" organisation="com.liferay" revision="latest.integration" />
 </info>

 <dependencies defaultconf="default">
  <dependency conf="test->default" name="arquillian-junit-container" org="org.jboss.arquillian.junit" rev="1.1.6.Final" />
  <dependency conf="test->default" name="arquillian-tomcat-remote-7" org="org.jboss.arquillian.container" rev="1.0.0.CR6" />
  <dependency conf="test->default" name="com.liferay.ant.arquillian" org="com.liferay" rev="1.0.0" />
 </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```